# How to render a particular tab

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need a help in my code. I have two tabs Login & Register. I want to render only Register Tab when I click on Register. I am not able to understand what to replace instead of users. For reference image is attached [login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CJJ4.png) & [register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6CRR.png)
My code is

```
router.post("/signup", function (req, res, next) {
const userSignUP = new signUp({
username: req.body.username,
email: req.body.email,
password: req.body.password,
});
userSignUP.save(function (err, data) {
if (err) throw err;
res.render("users", {
  title: "PassWord Management System",
  msg: "User Registered Successfully",
});
});
});
```

Comment: Could you share the code of the view `users`?

Comment: @Gpack sure here is my code [users](https://jsfiddle.net/akashjangra1989/sr1L9035/)

Comment: @Gpack Have you checked my code ?